# Running "IDLE3.2 -s" from the "Finder" in OS X 10.6

Tags: python, macos, shell

I want to run IDLE3.2 with the argument "-s" so it can read ".pythonstartup" and export relevant modules, change the working directory and etc. Here is what I have tried:

1. Created a shell script:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/idle3.2 -s
   ```

   this works allright, however running the script from the Finder opens up the Terminal, which is not the desired behavior.
2. Created an applescript:

   ```
   do shell script "/bin/bash; cd /usr/local/bin/; ./idle3.2 -s"
   ```

   this get rids of the terminal however fails to pass "-s" argument to idle3.2 so the configuration file is not loaded.

any suggestions?

**EDIT: turns out environment variables are not properly set** even though /bin/bash is called. so the following solves the problem:

```
do shell script "/bin/bash; source ~/.profile; /usr/local/bin/idle3.2 -s"
```

Comment: would it be more precise to say that the configuration file wasn't loaded so you *believe* that the -s argument wasn't passed? It's possible the script, for whatever reason doesn't have access to env vars that are required. I'd check there first - the Python docs say IDLESTARTUP and PYTHONSTARTUP are the ones to check.

Comment: certainly that could be the case:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2065/_index.html

here it says that "For security and portability reasons, do shell script ignores the configuration files that an interactive shell would read, so you don’t get the customizations you would have in Terminal."

Comment: thanks lain. i checked environment variables applescript is seeing and it turns out "source ~/.profile" wasn't called although i issued "/bin/bash/". so the following is working:

do shell script "/bin/bash; source ~/.profile; cd /usr/local/bin/;  ./idle3.2 -s"

Comment: please submit your solution as an answer and accept it; that way other people trying to solve this problem will more easily find it. (Try also your script without the leading `/bin/bash` -- I think that's just starting a new `bash`, which finds nothing to do and exits again -- it'd be nice if the accepted answer is the most concise mechanism :)

Comment: I agree with sarnold on both points; it's good to add your answer, and you don't need the /bin/bash as the default shell will be used anyway. You could always try `IDLESTARTUP=whatever_should_go_here /usr/local/bin/idle3.2 -s` or `env IDLESTARTUP=whatever_should_go_here /usr/local/bin/idle3.2 -s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to @lain the following applescript solves the problem:

```
do shell script "source ~/.profile; idle3.2 -s"
```

where ~/.profile points the shell (in this case /bin/sh) the path for .PYTHONSTARTUP and the path for idle3.2

Answer (score 2):

I think your `do shell script "/bin/bash; cd /usr/local/bin; ./idle3.2 -s"` is doing extra work, and can probably be done more simply. Try:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/idle3.2 -s"
```

Comment: I tend to prefer /usr/bin/env appname as I can use the $PATH and avoid hardcoded paths, but YMMV

Comment: @Iain, funny enough, I prefer hardcoded paths as a way to avoid using `$PATH`. :)